# Adding Lightbox2 functionality-a how to?

Tags: javascript

So I've been using Lightbox2 for my Lightbox. Great module, but I am very confused on how to Add functionality, like captions, text, and links to the Lightbox that is show the image. I know I need to add html, but where?!?! (rel="lightbox")

What I would like to do is show text only and some links on the image that is being used by Lightbox. So say I have Lightbox setup with Views. I go to the page with the images(no text), click on the image, and the lightbox with the image appears. Well, I want to show a caption text and maybe a link to my Ubercart ?

Is this possible and how?

Also can you add a module like hover preview to integrate with Lightbox2 ?

Comment: Have you seen the Drupal.org documentation on Lightbox2, specifically https://drupal.org/node/144488 and  https://drupal.org/node/735424 about Views integration?

Comment: How about integrating hover preview to Lightbox2?